# Can't configure port, username and database name on Testcontainers 3.2.0 MsSqlBuilder .NET

Tags: .net, testcontainers

I am trying to configure port, username and database name for MsSqlContainer but I can't find any approach for it. Here is my current code.

```
public class ApiFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
    {
        private readonly MsSqlContainer msSqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
            .WithHostname("mytestdb")
            .WithPassword("MyTestPassword$$123")
            .WithPortBinding(25555, true)
            .WithName("testcontainer")
            .Build();

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            try
            {
                this.msSqlContainer.StartAsync().Wait();
                var cn = this.msSqlContainer.GetConnectionString();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.msSqlContainer.StopAsync().Wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the generated connection string
"Server=127.0.0.1,53811;Database=master;UserId=sa;Password=MyTestPassword$$123;TrustServerCertificate=True"

MsSqlBuilder implicitly defines these settings.

```
public sealed class MsSqlBuilder : ContainerBuilder<MsSqlBuilder, MsSqlContainer, MsSqlConfiguration>
{
    public const string MsSqlImage = "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04";

    public const ushort MsSqlPort = 1433;

    public const string DefaultDatabase = "master";

    public const string DefaultUsername = "sa";

    public const string DefaultPassword = "yourStrong(!)Password";

    ...
}
```

Tried to find information in docs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is a little unclear, could you include which package / namespace this comes from?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Testcontainers are well know in .NET Community. The library is used to start docker container and host mssql server in it. Here is the lib https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new one using the one provided by the container:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_sqlServerContainer.GetConnectionString())
{
    InitialCatalog = "Database"
};
return builder.ConnectionString;
```